# How to stretch header across the screen

Tags: css

I have banner image that stretches the screen. I was told that the best
way to stretch is to load an image at the appropriate width. So doesn't that 
mean you need to use JavaScript to detect the screen resolution then load the appropriate image? However JS maybe disabled. Are there alternatives?

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: Can you embed the image so that we can see your desired effect?

Answer (score 2):

Set the image width in percentage. Notice the actual percentage will relate to the img's parents container.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure css.

```
img.banner {position:absolute; z-index:1; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

[Here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/background.html) is a demo by stu nicholls.